# Android Studio Display Bug

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-studio-2.2, android-studio-2.0

I'm re-writing a button with an arrow left Vector asset. Below piece of code works on my original project (following tutorial), and as I re-write this project just to practice, it just wouldn't show the vector asset. I even copy pasted all codes in every single file from my original project, still doesn't work.

However, as I cleared the copy pasted code and used the code I re-wrote, closed the new project and open again, the vector appeared.

My question is, right now I have a sample to compare with so I know I didn't make mistakes when re-writing. However in the future when I work alone, how do I know if it's my problem or if it's a bug? I may be scratching my head before checking to see if it's Android Studio's fault. This has happened quite a few times, usually when I work on XML layout files.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/prev_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/prev_button"
        app:icon="@drawable/arrow_left"
        app:iconGravity="start"/>
```

Comment: `However in the future when I work alone, how do I know if it's my problem or if it's a bug? ` realistically, for each and every scenario, you can't. write unit/UI tests and run it on an actual device to cover yourself for a few extra cases. perhaps screenshot tests could help